# sql group by different columns and count on different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table structure like below.

```
mode       ogn_city    dst_city      city 

flight     bengaluru    delhi
flight     kolkata      bengaluru
flight     delhi        mumbai
hotel                               mumbai
flight     mumbai       delhi
hotel                               kanpur
hotel                               bengaluru
```

need to get data on cities wise and the mode(both) count of that cities 
required output is like below

```
citi        flight_count   hotel_count
bengaluru     2             1
kolkata       1             0
delhi         2             0
mumbai        2             1
kanpur        0             1
```

I am able to get only one count but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate:

```
select city, sum(flight), sum(hotel)
from ((select ogn_city as city, 1 as flight, 0 as hotel
       from t
      ) union all
      (select dst_city, 1, 0
       from t
      ) union all
      (select city, 0, 1
       from t
      ) 
     ) t
where city is not null;
group by city;
```

Note:  The above uses the contents of the columns to determine if they are included.  You can also use `mode` instead:

```
select city, sum(flight), sum(hotel)
from ((select ogn_city as city, 1 as flight, 0 as hotel
       from t
       where mode = 'flight'
      ) union all
      (select dst_city, 1, 0
       from t
       where mode = 'flight'
      ) union all
      (select city, 0, 1
       from t
       where mode = 'hotel'
      ) 
     ) t
group by city;
```